# Javascript multidimentional array undefined object error

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, undefined

I am trying to make a two dimensional array out of two one dimentional arrays with this code:

```
  var PassAssoArr = new Array();
  for(k in PassPourcentNames) {
    PassAssoArr[k][0] = PassPourcentNames[k]
    PassAssoArr[k][1] = PassPourcentValue[k]
  }
```

However, I get the error message: " 'undefined' is null or not an object " and it points to the first line after the for statement.
PassPourcentNames and PassPourcentValue have the same number of elements and none of the values are null. The first one contain strings and the second one integers.

Any help is greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var PassAssoArr = new Array();
  for(k in PassPourcentNames) {
    PassAssoArr[k] = new Array();
    PassAssoArr[k][0] = PassPourcentNames[k]
    PassAssoArr[k][1] = PassPourcentValue[k]
  }
```

Also instead of `new Array()` you can use `[]`

```
  var PassAssoArr = [];
  for(k in PassPourcentNames) {
    PassAssoArr[k] = [];
    PassAssoArr[k][0] = PassPourcentNames[k]
    PassAssoArr[k][1] = PassPourcentValue[k]
  }
```

I believe this is actually faster in most JS engines.

Answer (score 1):

First define `PassAssoArr[k] = [];` before assigning to `[0]` and `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not support true multi-dimensional arrays.

You're trying to use nested arrays without creating the inner arrays.

You need to put an array into each element of the outer `PassAssoArr`:

```
PassAssoArr[index] = [];   //Empty array literal
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only defining one dimension of PassAssoArr - you need to set PassAssoArr[k] = new Array();

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing:

```
PassAssoArr[k] = new Array(PassPourcentNames[k], PassPourcentValue[k]);
```