# Populate specific array indices from other array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`. They're both 2-dimensional. I want to copy certain array values from `arr1` to `arr2`.

For instance, I want to copy the value from `arr1[9][9]` into `arr2[0][0]`. My guess was to write `arr2[0][0] = arr1[9][9];` but that failed.

I looked at some similar questions on this site but they did not answer my question.

---

Here is the code for the particular situation. The code is written is Google Apps script.

```
  // eplList and attList are both arrays. They are filled below (I checked, the values exist)
  var eplList = epl.getRange(2, 2, eplLastRow, 2).getValues();
  var attList = attsheet.getRange(3, 1, attLastRow, 20).getValues();

  var eplListLength = eplList.filter(String).length;
  var attListLength = attList.filter(String).length;

  // Declaring the empty array I want to fill
  var masterArray = [];

  var ix, jx, day;

  // Here I begin to fill the array
  for (ix = 0; ix < eplListLength; ix++)
  {
    masterArray[ix][0] = eplList[ix][0]; // This is where I am getting the error message 
    masterArray[ix][1] = eplList[ix][1];

      for (jx = 0; jx < attListLength; jx++)
      {
        if (eplList[ix][0] == attList[jx][day*4-4])
          masterArray[ix][6+day] = masterArray[ix][6+day].concat(" ", attList[jx][day*4-2], ": ",attList[jx][day*4-3]);
      };
 // and some morecode
  };
```

The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Comment: share your array data.

Comment: Share your arrays along with the error that you're getting

Comment: updating question. thank you

Comment: " but that failed." - what error did you get? Please provide more context.

Comment: @Toxy Mukherjee updated

Comment: You need to initialize the inner array: `masterArray[ix] = []` in the `for` loop. Also, the variable `day` is never set a value

Comment: @user256872 where? You need to initialize the each inner array. `for (ix = 0; ix < eplListLength; ix++) { masterArray[ix] = []; ` <-- here

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much. That worked. May I ask why do I have to initialize it twice? I why isn't declaring  `masterArray = []` sufficient?

Comment: You are only initializing the `masterArray` array. If you are populating that array, `masterArray[2] = 'somevalue'`, it would work fine. But, you are populating inner arrays. When `ix = 2`, initially the value `masterArray[2]` is undefined. There is nothing at that index. If you access `masterArray[2][0]`, you are trying to access `0` of undefined. So `masterArray[2] = []` will set that to an empty array. `masterArray[2][0] = ..` will set the value of that inner array`

Comment: Duplicate: [Javascript multidimentional array undefined object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix particular issue you've got try this code, but i not sure about code below):

`masterArray[ix] = [eplList[ix][0], eplList[ix][1]]; // This is where I am getting the error message`

Comment: So, you do not need this line at all: `masterArray[ix][1] = eplList[ix][1];`

Comment: No problem, what about code below (nested for). Did it fail?

Comment: so far so good, it's still in development :)

Comment: @user256872 you need to set the value of `day` somewhere. It's undefined and `6 + day` will return `NaN`

Comment: yes I have it set in my code I just accidentally removed it here. thank you